# Where is the full Kubernetes YAML spec?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

There *must* be "full-configuration" and example templates of Kubernetes YAML configs *somewhere* with comments itemizing what parameters do what with runnable examples somewhere.

Does anyone know where something like this might be? Or where the "full API" of the most commonly used Kubernetes components are?

Comment: https://github.com/helm/helm/tree/master/docs/examples/nginx/templates

Comment: did you try to find the answer before asking? a simple google search - kubernetes api reference will get you everything you need https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/ and https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/

Comment: it's strange kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/... this link is very hard to find, none of the other docs on kubernetes.io/docs/ reference to that link, and google never give that link in the seach result

Answer (score 20):

There is documentation for every k8s api version available, for example [check this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/).

The way I found what every key in yaml file represent and what does it mean is via `kubectl explain` command.

For example:

```
$kubectl explain deploy.spec
```

Trick I use while doing CKAD to see full list could be:

```
$kubectl explain deploy --recursive > deployment_spec.txt
```

This will list all available options for kubernetes deployment that could you use in yaml file.

To generate some template there is option to use `--dry-run` and `-o yaml` in `kubectl` command, for example to create template for CronJob:

```
$kubectl run cron_job_name --image=busybox --restart=OnFailure --schedule="*/1 * * * * " --dry-run -o yaml > cron_job_name.yaml
```

Comment: The last command results in "Error: unknown flag: --schedule". Plus, kubectl run is used to create a pod, not a cronjob.

Perhaps you meant "kubectl create cronjob cron_job_name --image=busybox --restart=OnFailure --schedule="*/1 * * * * " --dry-run -o yaml"